# integral estimation with midpoint

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $f\in C^2(\mathbb{R})$. Prove:

$$\int\limits_{x_0}^{x_0+\Delta x}f(x)dx=f\left(x_0+\frac{1}{2}\Delta x\right)\Delta x+O(\Delta x^3)$$

I tried using the integral mean value theorem to get a $c\in(x_0,x_0+\Delta x)$ such that

$$\int\limits_{x_0}^{x_0+\Delta x}f(x)dx=f(c)\Delta x$$

Then I said that if $c=x_0+\frac{1}{2}\Delta x$ we are done so we can assume w.l.o.g. that $c\in(x_0,x_0+\frac{1}{2}\Delta x)$. Now I tried using the regular mean value theorem to get $\xi\in(c,x_0+\frac{1}{2}\Delta x)$ such that

$$f'(\xi)=\frac{f(x_0+\frac{1}{2}\Delta x)-f(c)}{x_0+\frac{1}{2}\Delta x-c}$$

then we get

$$f(c)=f\left(x_0+\frac{1}{2}\Delta x\right)+f'(\xi)O(\Delta x)$$

But now I don't know how to get rid of the $f'(\xi)$ part in order to get the $O(\Delta x^3)$ estimation.

Comment: it is enough for $f(\xi)$ to be finite. Then you can absorb it in the big O.

Comment: @YvesDaoust but where does the $\Delta x^3$ come from. If I take the $f'(\xi)$ inside the O I will end up with $\Delta x^2$ which is not good for small $\Delta x$

Comment: Sorry, I meant $f'(\xi)$. Moving it inside the $O$ will not create a new $\Delta x$ factor, why would it ? And I was commenting on the "how to get rid" question.

Comment: Yes I know, so it is not sufficient to do so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the Taylor develoment,

$$f\left(x_0+\frac{t}2\right)=f\left(x_0+\frac{\Delta x}2\right)+tf'\left(x_0+\frac{\Delta x}2\right)+\frac{t^2}2f''\left(x_0+\frac{\Delta x}2\right)+O(\Delta x^2).$$

Then integrating bewteen $-\Delta x/2$ and $\Delta x/2$, the "$t$" term vanishes, and the next terms both yield an $O(\Delta x^3)$ contribution.